# Redis - Get single element by some "key"

Tags: c#, caching, azure, collections, redis

My team and I have an C# E-commerce engine. On this website we used memory cache, but cache migrated to redis.

We have a web application in azure with a hosted cache in azure redis too.

Whenever we needed a collection of cache use the `smembers` command.

Take for example the collection of products. Say we have 1,000 items in that cache collection.
Every time we have to access a product, we need to run the `smembers` command and get all the cache collection, it takes about 250 milliseconds. The problem is that by design of the application need to run this maybe 5 times on a single page, which greatly increases load times.

Example:

```
public Product GetProductById(int productId)
{
    Product product = null;
    try
    {
        List<Product> products = GetAllProducts();

        if (products != null && products.Count > 0)
            product = products.Find((p) => p.ProductId == productId);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return product;
}

public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    return GetCollectionFromSet<Product>(PRODUCTS_ALL_KEY);            
}

/// <summary>
/// SMEMBERS key 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Array reply: all elements of the set.
/// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/smembers</remarks>
public List<TEntity> GetCollectionFromSet<TEntity>(string Urn)
{
   try
   {
       List<TEntity> list = new List<TEntity>();
       IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
       RedisValue[] values2 = cache.SetMembers(Urn);

       foreach (RedisValue value in values2)
       {
           var entityInBit = Deserialize<TEntity>(value);
           list.Add(entityInBit);
        }
        return list;

        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
 }
```

StackOverflow miniprofiler example

[image: Load Time]

The big question is: Is there a way to get a single element without bringing the entire collection and filter through a C# LINQ?

Comment: First, why do you create another copy of the list you have just created: `List<Product> products = new List<Product>(GetAllProducts());` ? Any why not return Dictionary<int, Product> from your `GetAllProducts` method. where the key is the productId. Then you would have O(1) access time.

Comment: The problem is not how to make a linq, the problem is the hit to the cache. Once the collection is in memory that is faster, the problem is to bring the entire collection of a single element.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your issue? Do you want to retrieve only one element? Why do you need to perform 5 times this statement? Which Redis Client are you using?

Comment: By by design of the application, we havent a issue... its only a question: Is there a way to get a single element without bringing the entire collection and filter through a C# LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".  You're serializing your data into a format Redis knows nothing about so it cannot apply any filtering for you.

In order to get a much more efficient lookup you need to change the way you store data, for example, if each of your products is stored as a standard key you can do a direct O(1) lookup to fetch it - and if you know all the IDs up front you can pipeline this.